# Number change for input in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my code in Jquery. I have a form with radio buttons. One of them is with multiple choices and when clicked, inputs with: Choice #1 - Choice #2 - etc appear. My problem is that when I delete one of them: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 : I delete 4, it should BECOME: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4(the number 5 transforms into 4) but for me it remains: 1 - 2 - 3 - 5.
Does anyone have any solutions? The code is here:

```
$('.options').hide();

$('#single-answer').on('click', function() {
    $('.options').slideUp();
});

var choiceNumber = 2;
var answerNumber = 2;

$('#multiple-answer').on('click', function() {
    $('.options').slideDown();
    choiceNumber = 2;

    $('.add-choice').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        choiceNumber++;
        var input = "";
        input += "<li class='list' style='display:none'>Choice #" + choiceNumber + "<input type='text' name='choice' id='choice" + choiceNumber + "'>";
        input += "<input type='image' src='cross108.png' class='icon-del' alt='Submit'></li>";
        //$('.poll-list').append(input);
        $(input).appendTo('.poll-list').show('slow');
    }); 

    answerNumber = choiceNumber;
    $('ol').on('click', '.icon-del', function() {
        $(this).closest('.list').slideUp('slow', function(){ 
            $(this).closest('.list').remove(); 
        });
        choiceNumber -= 1;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code: why don't you simply rebuild the list after you delete an item?

Comment: Show please your markup.

Answer (score -1):

Hide - this only hides the option, it will still exit in hidden form

```
$('.options').hide();
```

You should use remove instead:

```
 $('.options').remove();
```

Comment: I guess this code doesn`t make "remove action" Kyuubido0 mentioned. Removal is performed here:  $('ol').on('click', '.icon-del', function() {
        $(this).closest('.list').slideUp('slow', function(){ 
            $(this).closest('.list').remove(); 
        });
        choiceNumber -= 1;
    });